# Displaying Excel in AxFramerControl control - refresh issues

Tags: excel

I'm using AxFramerControl in order to embed Excel worksheet in my application. The problem is - each time a dialog window or something like that obscures part of the worksheet, the worksheet is not repainted automatically. Calling axFramerControl.Refresh() doesn't help. What can be done?

Answer (score 0):

One alternative is [SpreadsheetGear for .NET](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/) which comes with an Excel compatible Windows Forms spreadsheet control.

You can download a free trial [here](https://www.spreadsheetgear.com/downloads/register.aspx).

Disclaimer: I own SpreadsheetGear LLC

Comment: is there a similar library that supports Word and Powerpoint format's too?